# jqPlot how to make a chart from java arraylist and JSF beans

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jsf-2, jqplot

I have been using Primefaces charts with some success but I want to learn more about jqPlot so I can do more flexible customization. An example is I want to create a combination chart (bar chart and line combo).

I want the chart to be created by firing a jQuery function from the XHTML page:

```
<button type="button" class="button" onclick="comboChart()">Combo Chart</button>
```

The function is:

```
            function comboChart() {

             var line1 = [#{chartDataBean.comboChartMapList}];
             var line2 = [#{chartDataBean.linePartChartMap}];

             var plot2 = $.jqplot('testchart', [line1, line2], {
                        series: [{renderer: $.jqplot.BarRenderer}, {xaxis: 'x2axis', yaxis: 'y2axis'}],
             axesDefaults: {
             tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer,
             tickOptions: {
                                angle: 30
                            }
                        },
                        axes: {
                            xaxis: {
                                renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer
                            },
                            x2axis: {
                                renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer
                            },
                            yaxis: {
                                autoscale: true
                            },
                            y2axis: {
                                autoscale: true
                            }
                        }
                    });
                };
```

The JSF bean contains an Array List of Maps where each map will be a series:

```
public List<HashMap<Object, Double>> getComboChartMapList() {
    List<List<Endatapoint>> modbinholder = new ArrayList<List<Endatapoint>>
();
    modbinholder = anBean.getModelBinList();
    comboChartMap = new HashMap<>();
    comboChartMapList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (List<Endatapoint> cList : modbinholder) {
        List<Endatapoint> pholder = new ArrayList<>();
        pholder = cList;
        for (Endatapoint p : pholder) {

            Date lDate = p.getPointdate();
            String pnits = p.getRecords().getSnipunit();

            Double aNum = p.getActualnum();
            comboChartMap.put(pnits, aNum);
            comboChartMapList.add(comboChartMap);
        }
    }
    return comboChartMapList;
}
```

The above just produces a blank chart with no data on it. Looking at the JS Console in Chrome and FF (Firebug) I notice a syntax error where the list values are generated like this:

```
  var line1 = [[{Million Dollars=54.7}, {Million Dollars=54.7}]];
```

But the jqplot documentation requires the values to be generated like this:

```
  var line1 = [['Million Dollars', 54], ['Million Dollars', 54.7]];
```

My questions are:

1. What am I doing wrong in the above code?
2. Can I pass the correct values using the above code or will I need to use any additional method like JSON?

Most of the examples and questions I read here seem to involve JSON in passing dynamic values to jplot. I would like to stick to just using Java objects if possible.

Comment: Json is required and that is what PrimeFaces behind the scenes does for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Json is required, PrimeFaces, or a rest interface with annotations, does that for you, just create a getter that does the conversion